# How to register UDF to use in SQL and DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

From what I have seen, in order to do this you have to

1. make the `udf` as a plain function
2. register the function with `SQLContext` for SQL

   ```
   spark.sqlContext.udf.register("myUDF", myFunc)
   ```
3. turn this into a `UserDefinedFunction` for `DataFrame`

   ```
   def myUDF = udf(myFunc)
   ```

Is there no way to combine this into one step and make the `udf` available for both? Also, for cases where a function exists for `DataFrame` but not for SQL, how do you go about registering it without copying over the code again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UDFRegistration.register` variants, which take a `scala.FunctionN`, return an `UserDefinedFunction` so you can register SQL function and create DSL friendly UDF in a single step:

```
val timesTwoUDF = spark.udf.register("timesTwo", (x: Int) => x * 2)
spark.sql("SELECT timesTwo(1)").show
```

```
+---------------+
|UDF:timesTwo(1)|
+---------------+
|              2|
+---------------+
```

```scala
spark.range(1, 2).toDF("x").select(timesTwoUDF($"x")).show
```

```
+------+
|UDF(x)|
+------+
|     2|
+------+
```

Comment: DSL: Domain Specific Language

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following and still apply it on dataframe

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register("myUDF", myFunc)
```

Use selectExpr when calling it on dataframe transformations.

```
df.selectExpr("myUDF(col1) as modified_col1")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Spark2**-

```
spark.udf.register("func_name", func_name)
```

> Argument1- Function name it will be register in spark

> Argument2- Function name what is defined while creating in python/scala

It's best practice to register the function with same name in spark.