# How to register Spark udf from SQL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to register a UDF like the following (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484317)):

```
val timesTwoUDF = spark.udf.register("timesTwo", (x: Int) => x * 2)
spark.sql("SELECT timesTwo(1)").show
```

but in SQL, importing the jar containing the udf, something like (found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html)):

```
ADD JAR 's3://path/to/my/udf.jar';
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION timesTwo as 'my.udf.package.Udfs.timesTwoUDF'; -- This does not seem to support non Hive UDFs
SELECT timesTwo(1)
```

Thanks